# chrome extension to wipe out page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a manifest file like so:

```
{
   "name":"Clear the Page",
   "version":"1.0",
   "default_locale":"en",
   "manifest_version":2,
   "permissions":[
      "background"
   ],
   "browser_action":{
      "default_icon":"icon.png"
   },
   "background":{
      "scripts":[
        "deleteThePage.js"
      ]
   }
}
```

then I made a deleteThePage.js file like so:

```
deletePage = function() {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
    xhr.send();
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { deletePage();});
```

...the idea being, when you click the icon, poof! the page is wiped out.

The extension loads without a problem, but nothing gets wiped out.

I'll be the first to admit I have no clue what I am doing here, just trying to piece this together from examples on the internet.

Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: You need to inject a content script to wipe the page, at the moment when you click the button you wipe the background page.

Comment: Indeed you have no clue, but [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) should be an important read in this case. Especially the Architecture part.